# can not pass variable to sampler's assertion in Jmeter - Groovy

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I try to make a test that read from DB and assert the data
I create a JDBC request and JSR223 sampler + Jsr223 assertion.
in the sampler I created a variable called sensativity_results.
and I want to pass it to the assertion.
I used

```
vars.putObject("sensativity_results", sensativity_results);
```

and then in the assertion I try to call it and print it,
the problem is that Jmeter just not recognized the assertion, 
Moreover I created another sampler called test to print the results of "sensativity_results" and Jmeter just pass it and not even execute it

```
int actual_sensativity ()
{
    float Actual_sensativity;
    int loop_num = vars.get("Loop_Number") as int; 
    int conversion_sense = vars.get("Conv_sens") as int;
    int actual_conversion = vars.get("Conv_numbers_1") as int;
    Actual_sensativity = (float) (actual_conversion/loop_num)*100;
    System.out.println("************** Actual_sensativity  in %:  " + Actual_sensativity);
    System.out.println("**conversion_sensativity:  " + conversion_sense);
    System.out.println("**actual_conversion:  " + actual_conversion);
    System.out.println("**loop number:  " + loop_num);
    return Actual_sensativity;

}




int sensativity_results;
sensativity_results = actual_sensativity();
vars.putObject("sensativity_results", sensativity_results);
System.out.println("sensativity_results:  " + sensativity_results);
```

the test plan ran as expected until this step and stopped without any error it print the sensitivity results at the first sampler, and just not move on, can someone please advise?

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just put vars.put("sensativity_results", sensativity_results);
and it solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will be using this `sensativity_results` variable as a [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) later on I would suggest storing it like:

```
vars.put("sensativity_results", String.valueOf(sensativity_results))
```

Otherwise you will get `ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` error on attempt to use it like `${sensativity_results}`

Alternative way of accessing non-String variables would be using __groovy() function (available since [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31)) like:

```
${__groovy(String.valueOf(vars.getObject('foo')),)}
```